# Нужна помощь в редактирование сайта на Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla

Нужно внести изменения на главную страницу сайта, у меня есть доступ к хостингу сайта, доступа к CMS(Joomla)- нет, подскажите пожалуйста что и как можно сделать в данной ситуацию.

Заказчик попросил на главную страницу сайта добавить пару блоков с сылками, они у меня уже сверстаны, но как интегрировать их на сайт я не представляю.
Весь контент в index.php подключен с помощь helix3->generatelayout(); ?> где можно редактировать эти 'layout?

Comment: Если у вас возникли сложности с выполнением конкретной задачи, опишите ее в вопросе подробнее. Потому что сейчас вопрос выглядит так, как будто вы спрашиваете "что мне делать чтобы получить несанкционированный доступ к CMS", а это немного не по теме.

Comment: Заказчик попросил на главную страницу сайта добавить пару блоков с сылками, они у меня уже сверстаны, но как интегрировать их на сайт я не представляю.
весь контент в index.php подключен с помощь
<?php $this->helix3->generatelayout(); ?>
где можно редактировать эти 'layout?'

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, так будет больше шансов получить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У вас на Joomla! установлен отдельный `HELIX framework`, для редактирования оcновного файла шаблона, вам надо зайти в `root->plugins->system->helix ....` там уже вам надо сориентироваться, по стандарту там должна быть папка `theme` в котором находится `default.php` и отдельная директория в которых находится несколько `php` файлов вашего шаблона, вам нужно редактировать `default.php` или `content.php`